# Why Bootstrap is not working?

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I'm new in bootstrap, so I can't make the nav display correctly

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Title</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link  href="./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
    <button class="btn btn-success">Botón Verde</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I used bower to install jquery and bootstrap. 
This is how it displayed:
https://ibb.co/bXhUdv

Comment: You need to close your `<head>` tag.

Comment: Also need a doctype.

Comment: You need to start the page with <!DOCTYPE html> You don't have a <title> tag in the head to    call out the page name and you didn't close </html> in the bottom line

Comment: Still not working

Comment: why is `./` used here?

Comment: To use the current directory

Comment: Check @syden answer.. The navbar is Bootstrap 4, but Bower is probably grabbing Bootstrap 3.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT based on comment:**

[To install boostrap 4 alpha 6 through bower do:](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/download/#bower)

```
bower install bootstrap#v4.0.0-alpha.6
```

**Original answer:**

Likely something with bower, are you positive you are loading bootstrap 4 alpha 6 and not bootstrap 3? Code seems fine on Fiddle, see below:

- Try loading it manually from a CDN and see if you can isolate the issue to bower
- Also consider loading all the JS files on their respective orders right before the `</body>` closing tag.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.3.7/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-md-0">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
<button class="btn btn-success">Botón Verde</button>
```

Comment: I typed "bower install bootstrap" I should have typed "bower install bootstrap # v4.0.0-alpha.6" specifying the bootstrap version. Thanks a lot for your help(:

Comment: `bower install bootstrap#v4.0.0-alpha.6` - also added reference above from the official docs :)